# How to redirect using AngularJS datatable button?

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

I am trying to redirect from one page to another using angularjs data table button. I am calling a function which contains the redirect url. The function is being called successfully but the redirection is not working. I am using `$location.path` to redirect. Am i doing this in right way or there are some other ways to redirect using data table button ?

```
   .withButtons([
   {
        text: 'Next Page',
        key: '1',
        action: function (e, dt, node, config) 
            {
               $scope.redirect();
            }
    }]);

    $scope.redirect=function() 
    {
       $location.path('/next_page');
    };
```

Comment: how do you implement the routes with ng-route or  ui-route

Comment: for routing i have used  ng-route

Comment: did thrown an error when call $location ?? , i dont see any sintaxis error, or something wrong it should work, if you can provide an plnkr with the issue will help.

Comment: ok i will try to update my question with an plunker.I forgot to mention one thing that i am using the button inside a modal.